# PHP lowest common denomination

Tags: php, html, opencart

I am working on a payment gateway and the amount parameter needs to formatted this way:
 `amount – (digits only) the integer value of the transaction in lowest common denomination (ex. $5.20 is 520)`
I have already removed the `$` and all values will be rounded to 2 decimal places.

In PHP if i try to cast amount as `int` ie `(int)$amount` I am going to loose the **.20** in the example though its needed. What could be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Multiply it by 100 and then convert to int.

Comment: Please provide a few more sample inputs amd your expected output so that we understand the variabilty of your input and your desired outputs.  Always 2 decimal places? Ever 3? Ever 0 decimals?

Comment: Always 2 decimal places. Example 45.67 becomes 4567, 45.00 becomes 4500

Comment: Is there a `$` at the start or only digits and a dot?

Comment: Already removed the `$`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can multiply the amount by 100 and then convert it...

```
$amount = (int)($amount*100);
```

So 5.20 becomes 520.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about the number of decimal places, you *could* use regex to strip non-digital values from your string.

```
echo preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $amount);
```

`\D` means any non-numeric character.  `+` means one or more.

If the value needs to be cast as an integer (rather than a string) write`(int)` just before `preg_replace`.

Of course, you could use `str_replace()` and target known characters like: `$` and `.` (and `-` if it may exist).

---

After some feedback from the OP...

You can round and format in one step with `number_format()`.

Code: ( Demo: https://3v4l.org/ir54s )

```
$amounts = array(0.001, 0.005, 5.20, 5.195, 5.204, 5);
foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
    echo  $amount , "->" , (int)number_format($amount, 2, '', '')."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0.001->0
0.005->1
5.2->520
5.195->520
5.204->520
5->500
```

Comment: This would be a how to do it if your starting with a string.

Comment: No idea, all the text says is that $5.20 is 520, so not sure if that is the value coming in or they just want to make the point that you need to send a value of $5.20 as 520.

Comment: I am interpreting the posted sample input literally.  Fact is, if the input data has a fixed number of decimal places, I'd be using your method.

Comment: I just wanted to make the point that if the input was a string, then your method is the way to go (hence the upvote).

Comment: This won't work on non float numbers. Example 1 becomes 1 with this method. But I believe it should be 100. Not sure but that is a quite common way for cash registers and such to handle numbers.

Comment: @Andreas that's a fair point.  I'm not sure what is expected in that case.  I don't know if the `100` is hard/fast.

Comment: Should we be using `number_format()` with an empty separator and empty decimal?

Comment: Don't know either. Just pointing out a possible problem with the method. I was about to type an answer earlier with str_replace to remove the dot, then I realized it's not the same result on integers. But who knows what op wants.

Comment: I already have removed the `$`  and rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @ovicko I have updated to show how to combine the rounding with reformatting.  This of course doesn't strip the dollar sign.